# Flutter wait for signal from firestore bool

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about Flutter and Firestore.
I want to wait until another app set the bool from Firestore "roomStart" to true, to open a view. If "roomStart" is false, it should wait until it is set to true and then start the if statement again.

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Room room;
  QuizPage(this.questions, this.room);
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState(room);
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {

  final Room room;
  _QuizPageState(this.room);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(room.roomStart) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        //code
);
    } else {
      // code: wait for boolean is set on true
      );
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZjj2.png)

The idea i had was to set a setState but i still lack the right approach, does anyone have an example or a hint?

I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Firebase SDK` you can get a `Stream` of data for your `Document` (Room) by calling `onSnapshot()` with `firebase_cloudstore`. The `Stream` will always output the latest value from firebase. You don't necessarily have to have a `StatefulWidget`, instead you can use a `StatelessWidget` with a `StreamBuilder` and you can put your `if` logic inside of the `StreamBuilder`s `builder` method.

Make sure to check that the `snapshot` `hasData` and show the appropriate widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streambuilder and listen snapshot as

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('roomCollectionName')
          .document('roomId')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          if (snapshot.data['roomstart']) {
            //true
            return Container();
          } else {
            //false
            return Container();
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```